# is there any way to dynamically load css file with webpack

Tags: css, dynamic, webpack, webpack-2, code-splitting

Webpack has a code splitting feture(use require.ensure or System.import) which make us dynamically load our js files. But I want to know if there is  any way to dynamically load css file?

It is so weird since I dynamically load my js files while I load my css files only in one time.

In my project, I make my css files in seperate entries and use extractTextPlugin to compile them as a extra css files. And load them in link tag.

Comment: Can someone provide a code, i wanna do the same but there is no other post out there which describes the part discussed here.
Please :)

Answer (score 1):

You can, but they will not be loaded as CSS files (with ExtractTextPlugin), but from JS, injected with style-loader (which is perfectly alright).

There are only a few things to do. Make sure you set up your CSS/SASS/LESS/...-loaders correctly. If ExtractTextPlugin already works you're good on that point. Then also make sure you have `fallbackLoader` set to `style-loader` (and `allChunks` set to the default: `false`) in your `ExtractTextPlugin.extract({})` loader.

At that point, just use `require.ensure` or `System.import` to require/import your CSS files, exactly as you would do with code. Thanks to the magic of webpack, things will just magically work!

Comment: It seems it doesn't work. Can you  give me an example?

Comment: webpack compiles the css file. However, the System.import('cssfile') does not load the css file.

Comment: OK, I got it. I seems I make something wrong. Any way, it works now. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi. The comments above were few months ago, but could you help me with the specific configuration that works for you? I have the same requirement but not success so far. Im using amd and below is my css loader configuration.
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: "style-loader", use: "css-loader", publicPath: "./" })
                }

Answer (score -4):

I used the following setup successfully to load styles dynamically for different tenants.

https://github.com/shiranGinige/react-redux-starter-with-login/blob/master/README.md